# sentence combine with past tense and present continuous tense

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence correct?
I have confirmed their result, also showing that their theory is acceptable.

I suppose that it involves very basic grammar, but I am just not sure. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your example has neither a past nor a present continuous construction. If it did, it would read thus:

> I confirmed their results and am also showing that their theory is acceptable.

That would indeed be grotesque; but your example is acceptable:

- Your main clause, *I've confirmed their results*, is headed by a verb in the present perfect. This expresses a present state, the confirmation of the results, which arises from your prior action.
- *showing that their theory is acceptable* is a subordinate clause headed by the present participle of the verb *show*. This form is ‘non-finite’—it is not marked for tense, and it ‘borrows’ its time reference from the main clause.

Both clauses thus refer to the same timeframe: the present.